# Karma+Jasmine tests not running with Chrome, "Executed 0 of 0 ERROR"

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test my project angular 5 with **jasmine** and **karma** but it show me this error:

```js
myProject\Front\src\app> ng test
Your global Angular CLI version (7.0.3) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
30 10 2018 09:42:25.435:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
30 10 2018 09:42:38.011:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
30 10 2018 09:42:38.016:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
30 10 2018 09:42:41.074:INFO [Chrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket RiQkM_n-0oc-xuYAAAAA with id 49828596
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in `configure`'

Chrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.003 secs / 0 secs)
```

and this is my **karma.conf.js** :

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Oct 29 2018 16:09:43 GMT+0000 (Maroc)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        //plugin needed
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        ],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'src/app/*.spec.ts',
        ],


        // list of files / patterns to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {

        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

[and this the interface in Google Chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MXPJ.png)

I'm just a beginner  and I'm not sure if those informations are enough. I tried a lot of solutions that I found but always the same problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: What versions of karma/karma-jasmine/karma-chrome-launcher are you using?

Comment: @Acey i upgrade my angular to 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a result of an incompatibility with newer versions of Chrome (failing for me with version 70) and the newest version of jasmine (3.3.0). The short term workaround is to lock your jasmine-core version to 3.2.0.

Comment: As a beginner with Jasmine and Karma I would have lost my mind trying to figure out what was causing this. Thank you immensely.